# How to create a list in C using list()? (Trying to save and extract elements to/from the list)

Tags: c, list

How can I create a list in C using list()? Not a linked list, just a regular list of elements. I am coming from python where I can just use list = []. But the only thing that turns up when I Google "list in C" are linked lists. It appears that there is a function list() that I am assuming creates a list. I cannot figure out how to extract the first and second values:

```
    int L = list(1,2,3,4,5);
    int a = L[0];
    int b = L[1];
```

I need to make a list in C to store two values, a numerator (n) and a denominator (d). I am creating a fraction calculator and I want n and d to be the two values I store in the fractions (lists). I don't want to write a program with f1 = (n1, d1) through fk = (nk, dk).

Comment: C don't have lists. If you want [linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) you need to code them (with heap allocated `struct` containing pointers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw 2 questions there:

1. How to use a data structure to store non-atomic type variable
2. How to create a (homogenous) array of such structures.

Python lists have no direct equivalent, since C cannot store heterogenous data types off the shelf of arbitrary length. You may need some deeper background reading, but here's some sample code that might help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Define a structure type, no builtin tuples
typedef struct { 
    int n;
    int d;
} Fraction;


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i;
    int N = 5; 
    Fraction f0 =  {2, 3};  // Directly create & initialize data 
    Fraction *fractions;    // variable length ponter to array of Fractions 

     
    // Using dynamic allocation of arrays
    fractions =  (Fraction *) malloc(N*sizeof(Fraction));  
    fractions[0] = f0;                   
    fractions[1] = (Fraction) {5, 7};    // This needs to be explicitly casted to Fraction type
    fractions[2] = (Fraction) {11, 13}; 
    fractions[3] = (Fraction) {17, 19}; 
    fractions[4] = (Fraction) {23, 29}; 


    printf ("Fraction0 -> numerator: %d, denominator: %d\n", f0.n, f0.d); 

    for (i=1; i < N; i++) {
        printf ("Fractions[%d] -> numerator: %d, denominator: %d\n", i, fractions[i].n, fractions[i].d); 
    }
}
```

This should print:

> Fraction0 -> numerator: 2, denominator: 3
>
> Fractions[1] -> numerator: 5, denominator: 7
>
> Fractions[2] -> numerator: 11, denominator: 13
>
> Fractions[3] -> numerator: 17, denominator: 19
>
> Fractions[4] -> numerator: 23, denominator: 29

Comment: This is a lot closer to what I am trying to accomplish. I am trying to scan in a numerator and a denominator. Thanks for your help.

Comment: One more question: If I was trying to use a scanf to give n and d a value how would I do that? I have tried using &(f->Fraction.n), &Fraction.n, Fraction.n, and simply &n but none of those are working.

Comment: You're welcome. Try:  `scanf("%d %d", &f0.n, &f0.d);`. If you're using "f" as an array/pointer, then it would be something like `f = &f0; scanf("%d %d", &(f->n), &(f->d));` Just remember to first assign "f" to an allocated struct otherwise a segfault will probably occur down the line.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent in C would be an array of elements:

```
int x[10];
```

Is an array of `int`s and its size = 10

Initializing an array in C can be done in several ways, for example:

```
int x[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int x[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

Or you can assign a single element:

```
int x[10];
x[0] = 0;
x[1] = 1;
.
.
x[9] = 9;
```

You should read more about arrays and how they work in c.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a list in C. `list` is not in the C standard library, so I'm not sure where you found that. In C, you would generally use an array.

```
int L[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int a = L[0];
int b = L[1];
```

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that Sublime Text color codes a word if I put () behind it. I thought it was recognizing it like it would an int or a struct since it displayed as the same color.

Comment: @DanO'Connell No problem. If one of the answers solved your problem, please make sure to accept it.